# Quartz Clustered job - multiple hosts - Parallel Startup

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Has anyone tried to start Quartz Job application in parallel where application is running in multiple machines?

I have created Quartz Clustered job in my application which runs in multiple machines.
Quartz works fine when I start application Sequentially, in all host one by one. However, when I start the application in parallel, I am getting a few different kinds of errors.

Such as:

1. Registration of jobs and triggers failed: null 
   org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store Trigger with name: 'triggerName' and group: 'JOB_GROUP', because one already exists with this identification
2. ORA-02292: integrity constraint (QUARTZ_CRON_TRIG_TO_TRIG_FK) violated - child record found

Has anyone come across this issue and got it resolved?
Could you please share your thoughts on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue came, because i created SchedulerFactoryBean with following attribute.

-- `SchedulerFactoryBean.setOverwirteExistingJobs(true)`

While starting all the instance in Parallel, all the instance tried to remove Quartz_JOB_DETAILS and Quartz_TRIGGERS table value. which end in the above errors.

but,once i use default value "overwriteExisitingJobs is false". this issue has been disappeared.

Only problem i was facing is, every time if i change cron trigger value, i have remove JOB Information from DB and it will be created freshly while starting first scheduler instance.

```
delete from QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS;
delete from QRTZ_TRIGGERS;
delete from QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS;
delete from QRTZ_LOCKS;
commit;
```